# Using the steady state approximation in the decomposition of nitramide to determine rate law

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics, rate-equation

> $\ce{O2NNH2 (aq) ->[\mathit{k}_1] O2NNH- (aq) + H+ (aq)}$
> $\ce{O2NNH- (aq) + H+ (aq) ->[\mathit{k}_{-1}]  O2NNH2 (aq)}$
> $\ce{O2NNH- (aq) ->[\mathit{k}_2] N2O(g) + OH- (aq)}$
> $\ce{H+ (aq) + OH- (aq) ->[\mathit{k}_3] H2O(l)}$
>
> We assumed the first two steps were fast and gave a rapid pre-equilibrium, while the third step that generated $\ce{N2O}$ was slow. The last step is very fast.
>
> (i) For this question, use the steady state approximation for [$\ce{O2NNH-}$], assuming it is a reactive intermediate, to derive an expression for the rate law.

> The solution given is
>  $$\frac{\mathrm d [\ce{N2O}]}{\mathrm d t} = k_\mathrm{obs}\frac{\ce{[O2NNH2]}}{\ce{[H+]}}$$

My attempt at the solution is as follows:

$$\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{N2O}]}{\mathrm dt} = k_2\ce{[O2NNH-]}$$

Using the steady state approximation,

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{O2NNH-}]}{\mathrm dt} = k_1[\ce{O2NNH2}] - &k_{-1}[\ce{O2NNH-}][\ce{H+}] - k_2[\ce{O2NNH-}] = 0 \\
\ce{[O2NNH-]} &= \frac{k_1[\ce{O2NNH2}]}{(k_{-1}\ce{[H+]} + k_2)} \\
\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{N2O}]}{\mathrm dt} &= \frac{k_2k_1[\ce{O2NNH2}]}{(k_{-1}\ce{[H+]} + k_2)}
\end{align}

I have done this so far, but this doesn’t seem right to me. I’ve been looking over at it for seemingly ages but I can’t see where I am going wrong or if I have misunderstood something about the steady state approximation. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

This should help for future reference.. I'll fix the text up this time. Take care that you format the text so it is easier for people with text readers.

Comment: You must next assume $k_2$ is small wrt $k_{-1}[H^+]$  to get the answer given.

Comment: How have you come up with your equation for the production of N2O, the one just under "Using the steady state approximation". The last term, −k2[O2NNH−], is telling me that the rate of production of N2O decreases if there is more O2NNH−, do you think this can be right? Also apply the steady state approximation to the fast equation - the whole point is that the quick ones reach steady state compared to the slow one.

Comment: That should be for the rate of [O2NNH-], apologies someone edited this and I don’t know how to change it

Comment: @MarinaCalder - ah, OK, that makes sense now. I've submitted an edit correcting, hopefully it will get accepted soon. In that case the earlier comment by porphyrin has the answer for you